# Show that there exists a $λ ∈ K$ such that $l(A) = λtrace(A)$ for all $A ∈ Mat_{n,n}(K)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, vectors, trace

Hey I want to check my solutions with this problem. Can someone help me?

Let $K$ be a field, $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, and $l: Mat_{n,n}(K) → K$ a linear form such that $l(AB) = l(BA)$ for all $A, B ∈ Mat_{n,n}(K)$.

Show that there exists a $λ ∈ K$ such that $l(A) = λtrace(A)$ for all $A ∈ Mat_{n,n}(K)$.

Remark: In particular, show that there is, up to scalar multiples, only one linear form $l: Mat_{n,n}(K) → K$ such that $l(AB) = l(BA)$ for all $A, B$.

To solve this problem, we first define the linear form $l: Mat_{n,n}(K) → K$ as $l(A) = trace(A)$ for all $A ∈ Mat_{n,n}(K)$, where$ trace(A)$ denotes the trace (i.e., the sum of the diagonal entries) of the matrix A.

Next, we show that this linear form satisfies the condition $l(AB) = l(BA)$ for all $A, B ∈ Mat_{n,n}(K)$:

$l(AB) = trace(AB) = trace(BA) = l(BA)$

Therefore, $l$ satisfies the given condition.

To show that any linear form satisfying the condition must be a scalar multiple of trace, let $l: Mat_{n,n}(K) → K$ be a linear form such that $l(AB) = l(BA)$ for all $A, B ∈ Mat_{n,n}(K)$. Let $E_{i,j}$ be the matrix with $1$ in the $(i,j)$ position and $0$ elsewhere, and let $e_i$ be the column vector with $1$ in the i-th position and $0$ elsewhere.

Then, for any $i$ and $j$, we have:

$l(E_{i,i}E_{j,j}) = l(E_{j,j}E_{i,i})$

$l(e_i^Te_j) = l(e_j^Te_i)$

Therefore, $l(e_i^Te_j) = 0$ for all $i ≠ j$.

Now, let $A = (a_{i,j})$ be any matrix in $Mat_{n,n}(K)$, and let $B = (b_{i,j})$ be the matrix defined by $b_{i,j} = e_i^Te_j$. Then, for any $i$ and $j$, we have:

$l(a_{i,j}b_{i,j}) = l(b_{i,j}a_{i,j})$

$a_{i,j}l(b_{i,j}) = b_{i,j}l(a_{i,j})$

$a_{i,j}l(e_i^Te_j) = e_i^Te_jl(a_{i,j})$

$a_{i,j}l(e_i)^T e_j = e_i^T l(A)e_j$

Therefore, $l(A) = λtrace(A)$ for some $λ ∈ K$, where $λ = l(e_i)^T$ for any $i$.

Hence, we have shown that any linear form satisfying the condition must be a scalar multiple of trace, and that the linear form $l(A) = trace(A)$ satisfies the condition. Therefore, there exists a unique (up to scalar multiples) linear form $l: Mat_{n,n}(K) → K$ such that $l(AB) = l(BA)$ for all $A, B ∈ Mat_{n,n}(K)$, and it is given by $l(A) = λtrace(A)$ for some $λ ∈ K$.

Comment: This is not a question, this is a solution to an exercise.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim on this site are also accepted questions relating to verifying one's proofs, though usually you want to add the tag "solution-verification" in that case.

Comment: I didn't know it, sorry @BrunoB

Comment: It's fine. Just swap the trace-map tag for solution-verification and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Ah, I missed the first line asking for verification. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance, the general idea looks fine.  We can clean things up slightly.

A linear form is determined by its values on a basis, so it suffices to show that $\ell(E_{ij})=0$ when $i\neq j$ and $\ell(E_{ii})=\ell(E_{jj})$.  Using the multiplication relation between the one-non-zero element matrices $E_{ab}E_{cd}=\delta_{bc}E_{ad}$, we get rather clean computations.

For the first claim $$\ell(E_{ij})=\ell(E_{ij}E_{jj})=\ell(E_{jj}E_{ij})=\ell(0)=0$$

For the second claim,

$$\ell(E_{ii})=\ell(E_{ij}E_{jj}E_{ji})=\ell(E_{jj}E_{ji}E_{ij})=\ell(E_{jj}^2)=\ell(E_{jj}).$$

To be clear, this is just a slightly cleaner reformulation of what I believe your underlying ideas/computations are.